# CORS requests are not contains the samesite cookies

Tags: cookies, cross-domain, samesite

I'm having a website that allows for CORS sharing, and that's an intended behavior from them,
However, when I try to send a Cross-Origin request the "SameSite" cookies won't be set for the request,

After digging deeper for this I've found if any website sends a normal form request to the targeted website and then went back and resend it the "SameSite" Cookie will be set for the second request. as example :

1. Create a post form to http://devs.aaa.com
2. Submit the request and the cookies won't be set
3. Click on go back on the browser and re-submit the request
4. The cookies will be sent with the request

I tried to make a CORS that will help me to do the steps above with XMLHTTPRequest or any alternatives, that re-send the request but I've terribly failed !!

Answer (score 1):

`SameSite` cookies aren't set on cross-site POST requests.

You should use `SameSite=None; Secure` if you need to support cross-site AJAX requests.